# anonymous ASP.net form with SSL, sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, ssl

Hi I want to create contact form with SSL. I have created simple asp.net contact form without ssl and now i must add it. It is in Sharrepoint project but seems to be the same case as in asp.net form.
I have anonymous webapplication and won't be any login usecase, so whole webapplication must work via http://  but when user go to contact form, it must work via https://
I know how to do the redirect to https:// programatically, I've been searching how to configure SSL on IIS but it seems to not be the case?? I don't wont whole webappliation to work via https, only my contact form 
- how to do that and how o onfigure that?
The data from my form will be passed to database, but it is not important here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not practical to try to apply an SSL certificate for anything lower than the IIS application level -- in other words, *not* at the single page level like you asked.

You can either run the entire site with both SSL and non-SSL at the same time, which is no problem, then have your code check per page and redirect the user as appropriate.

Or you could create the contact form as its own application and make it a virtual directory in IIS and set that just that virtual directory to use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up for SSL, and then you can do as Mufasa said.  Just set it for the one page by coding your links that point to that page to use HTTPS instead of HTTP, and code in the page to detect if they tried to manually visit the page via HTTP.

If you don't know how to create the SSL request, you can follow this:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/56bdf977-14f8-4867-9c51-34c346d48b04.mspx?mfr=true

But you need to create the request, submit it to a 3rd party for approval (like Thawte), then add it into IIS to complete the process.